# Windows program on Wine works if launched from the directory where its executable is located, but crashes otherwise

Tags: 16.04, windows, wine, games

I have a Windows game (Geometry Dash) which works perfectly if I start it from Nautilus or cd to its directory and launch it either with `wine GeometryDash.exe` or `wine ~/Desktop/IronPig/Progs/Geometry\ Dash/GeometryDash.exe`.

But, if my current working directory is not the directory where the executable is located and I use the command `wine ~/Desktop/IronPig/Progs/Geometry\ Dash/GeometryDash.exe`  I get a window with the title: `Program Error`.

In that window there is also a show details button which navigates me to the following error message:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x0000000c in 32-bit code (0x00c1ec98).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:00c1ec98 ESP:0033fb74 EBP:0033fb74 EFLAGS:00010212(  R- --  I   -A- - )
 EAX:00000000 EBX:038c22e8 ECX:038c22e8 EDX:006cbf18
 ESI:038c22e8 EDI:00000000
Stack dump:
0x0033fb74:  0033fbcc 0058b58f 00000000 36e58700
0x0033fb84:  038c22e8 0033fd28 36e58700 038c22e8
0x0033fb94:  038c22e8 440e8000 43a00000 00c61431
0x0033fba4:  0033fbb0 36e58752 038c22e8 3f000000
0x0033fbb4:  3f000000 038c22e8 0033fbe8 00cd86e6
0x0033fbc4:  620b6791 0033fbf4 0033fbf4 0058b443
000c: sel=0067 base=00000000 limit=00000000 32-bit rw-
Backtrace:
=>0 0x00c1ec98 in libcocos2d (+0x5ec98) (0x0033fb74)
  1 0x0058b58f in geometrydash (+0x18b58e) (0x0033fbcc)
  2 0x0058b443 in geometrydash (+0x18b442) (0x0033fbf4)
  3 0x0043ccde in geometrydash (+0x3ccdd) (0x0033fcac)
  4 0x00c8109c in libcocos2d (+0xc109b) (0x0033fcf8)
  5 0x00660243 in geometrydash (+0x260242) (0x0033fde4)
  6 0x006612cb in geometrydash (+0x2612ca) (0x0033fe30)
  7 0x7b46068c call_process_entry+0xb() in kernel32 (0x0033fe48)
  8 0x7b4616d4 in kernel32 (+0x516d3) (0x0033fe88)
  9 0x7bc809ac call_thread_func_wrapper+0xb() in ntdll (0x0033fea8)
  10 0x7bc8397d call_thread_func+0xfc() in ntdll (0x0033ffa8)
  11 0x7bc8098a RtlRaiseException+0x21() in ntdll (0x0033ffc8)
  12 0x7bc529b3 call_dll_entry_point+0x3d2() in ntdll (0x0033ffe8)
  13 0xf7e21b7d wine_call_on_stack+0x1c() in libwine.so.1 (0x00000000)
  14 0xf7e21ce0 wine_switch_to_stack+0x1f() in libwine.so.1 (0xffa82248)
  15 0x7bc589be LdrInitializeThunk+0x24d() in ntdll (0xffa82298)
  16 0x7b46780a __wine_kernel_init+0xa69() in kernel32 (0xffa83408)
  17 0x7bc59893 __wine_process_init+0x152() in ntdll (0xffa83478)
  18 0xf7e1fd37 wine_init+0x2c6() in libwine.so.1 (0xffa834d8)
  19 0x7c000ac2 main+0x81() in <wine-loader> (0xffa83928)
  20 0xf7c34637 __libc_start_main+0xf6() in libc.so.6 (0x00000000)
0x00c1ec98: pushl   0xc(%eax)
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (147 modules)
PE    340000-  353000   Deferred        pthreadvce2
PE    360000-  3e4000   Deferred        libtiff
PE    400000-  a8d000   Export          geometrydash
PE    a90000-  bb7000   Deferred        libcurl
PE    bc0000-  d75000   Export          libcocos2d
PE    d80000-  df1000   Deferred        msvcp120
PE    e00000-  eee000   Deferred        msvcr120
PE    ef0000-  f78000   Deferred        sqlite3
PE    f80000- 1031000   Deferred        steam_api
PE   1040000- 11eb000   Deferred        fmod
PE  10000000-1004a000   Deferred        libextensions
PE  5a4c0000-5a4d3000   Deferred        zlib1
PE  62aa0000-62af4000   Deferred        glew32
ELF 7651f000-78520000   Deferred        libnvidia-glcore.so.384.111
PE  78520000-785c3000   Deferred        msvcr90
PE  78aa0000-78b5f000   Deferred        msvcr100
ELF 7a800000-7a935000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7a820000-7a935000   \               opengl32
ELF 7b400000-7b7e2000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b410000-7b7e2000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcf6000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcf6000   \               ntdll
ELF 7c000000-7c004000   Dwarf           <wine-loader>
ELF 7c618000-7c644000   Deferred        libvorbis.so.0
ELF 7c644000-7c64d000   Deferred        libogg.so.0
ELF 7c64d000-7c663000   Deferred        libgpg-error.so.0
ELF 7c663000-7c6d8000   Deferred        libpcre.so.3
ELF 7c6d8000-7c764000   Deferred        libvorbisenc.so.2
ELF 7c764000-7c7c4000   Deferred        libflac.so.8
ELF 7c7c4000-7c7e1000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7c7e1000-7c890000   Deferred        libgcrypt.so.20
ELF 7c890000-7c8b6000   Deferred        liblzma.so.5
ELF 7c8b6000-7c8dc000   Deferred        libselinux.so.1
ELF 7c8dc000-7c8e5000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7c8e5000-7c95e000   Deferred        libsndfile.so.1
ELF 7cb38000-7cb3f000   Deferred        libasyncns.so.0
ELF 7cb3f000-7cbcd000   Deferred        libsystemd.so.0
ELF 7cbcd000-7cc27000   Deferred        libdbus-1.so.3
ELF 7cc27000-7ccaf000   Deferred        libpulsecommon-8.0.so
ELF 7ccaf000-7cd09000   Deferred        libpulse.so.0
ELF 7cd33000-7cd5c000   Deferred        winepulse<elf>
  \-PE  7cd40000-7cd5c000   \               winepulse
ELF 7cd5c000-7ce8f000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7cd70000-7ce8f000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7ce8f000-7ceb2000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>
  \-PE  7ce90000-7ceb2000   \               mmdevapi
ELF 7d30d000-7d317000   Deferred        libwrap.so.0
ELF 7d317000-7d323000   Deferred        libjson-c.so.2
ELF 7d5b4000-7d6cc000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7d6f6000-7d6fd000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7d6fd000-7d709000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7d709000-7d71c000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7d71c000-7d720000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7d720000-7d72d000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7d72d000-7d739000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7d739000-7d740000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7d740000-7d744000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7d744000-7d74b000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7d74b000-7d74f000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF 7d74f000-7d775000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7d775000-7d8c0000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7d8c0000-7d8d5000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7d8f8000-7d8fd000   Deferred        libnvidia-tls.so.384.111
ELF 7d8ff000-7d98c000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7d910000-7d98c000   \               winex11
ELF 7d98c000-7d9a2000   Deferred        dwmapi<elf>
  \-PE  7d990000-7d9a2000   \               dwmapi
ELF 7d9a2000-7d9c6000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7d9b0000-7d9c6000   \               imm32
ELF 7d9e5000-7da0f000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7da0f000-7da58000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7da58000-7da83000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7da83000-7db33000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7db5d000-7db88000   Deferred        msacm32<elf>
  \-PE  7db60000-7db88000   \               msacm32
ELF 7db88000-7dc08000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7db90000-7dc08000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7dc08000-7dd41000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7dc20000-7dd41000   \               ole32
ELF 7dd41000-7ddf9000   Deferred        winmm<elf>
  \-PE  7dd50000-7ddf9000   \               winmm
ELF 7ddf9000-7de70000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7de10000-7de70000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7de70000-7e0b2000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7de80000-7e0b2000   \               shell32
ELF 7e0b2000-7e0d5000   Deferred        libtinfo.so.5
ELF 7e0d5000-7e0fb000   Deferred        libncurses.so.5
ELF 7e111000-7e125000   Deferred        psapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e120000-7e125000   \               psapi
ELF 7e125000-7e13a000   Deferred        xinput1_3<elf>
  \-PE  7e130000-7e13a000   \               xinput1_3
ELF 7e13a000-7e14e000   Deferred        xinput9_1_0<elf>
  \-PE  7e140000-7e14e000   \               xinput9_1_0
ELF 7e14e000-7e177000   Deferred        iphlpapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e150000-7e177000   \               iphlpapi
ELF 7e177000-7e23b000   Deferred        msvcrt<elf>
  \-PE  7e190000-7e23b000   \               msvcrt
ELF 7e23b000-7e255000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7e240000-7e255000   \               version
ELF 7e255000-7e3b2000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e270000-7e3b2000   \               user32
ELF 7e3b2000-7e3bb000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7e3bb000-7e3ed000   Deferred        libcrypt.so.1
ELF 7e3ed000-7e4ce000   Deferred        libsqlite3.so.0
ELF 7e4ce000-7e51e000   Deferred        libhx509.so.5
ELF 7e51e000-7e52f000   Deferred        libheimbase.so.1
ELF 7e52f000-7e559000   Deferred        libwind.so.0
ELF 7e559000-7e5e5000   Deferred        libgmp.so.10
ELF 7e5e5000-7e61a000   Deferred        libhogweed.so.4
ELF 7e61a000-7e657000   Deferred        libnettle.so.6
ELF 7e657000-7e66c000   Deferred        libtasn1.so.6
ELF 7e66c000-7e6a0000   Deferred        libidn.so.11
ELF 7e6a0000-7e701000   Deferred        libp11-kit.so.0
ELF 7e701000-7e71c000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e71c000-7e734000   Deferred        libroken.so.18
ELF 7e734000-7e76d000   Deferred        libhcrypto.so.4
ELF 7e76d000-7e81e000   Deferred        libasn1.so.8
ELF 7e81e000-7e8b6000   Deferred        libkrb5.so.26
ELF 7e8b6000-7e8c0000   Deferred        libheimntlm.so.0
ELF 7e8c0000-7ea18000   Deferred        libgnutls.so.30
ELF 7ea18000-7ea5f000   Deferred        libgssapi.so.3
ELF 7ea5f000-7ea7d000   Deferred        libsasl2.so.2
ELF 7ea7d000-7ea96000   Deferred        libresolv.so.2
ELF 7ea96000-7eaa6000   Deferred        liblber-2.4.so.2
ELF 7eaa6000-7eb01000   Deferred        libldap_r-2.4.so.2
ELF 7eb01000-7eb5b000   Deferred        wldap32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb10000-7eb5b000   \               wldap32
ELF 7eb5b000-7eb95000   Deferred        ws2_32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb60000-7eb95000   \               ws2_32
ELF 7eb95000-7ec0c000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eba0000-7ec0c000   \               advapi32
ELF 7ec0c000-7ed3c000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7ec20000-7ed3c000   \               gdi32
ELF 7ef3c000-7ef4f000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ef4f000-7ef5c000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ef5c000-7ef77000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef77000-7ef81000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF 7ef81000-7efd6000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe5000-7f000000   Deferred        wsock32<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               wsock32
ELF f7c17000-f7c1c000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f7c1c000-f7dd2000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f7dd2000-f7def000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7e13000-f7e18000   Deferred        libcom_err.so.2
ELF f7e19000-f7fd0000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f7fd1000-f7ff6000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f7ff9000-f7ffa000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
00000008 (D) Z:\home\ironpig\Desktop\IronPig\Progs\Geometry Dash\GeometryDash.exe
    0000002d    2
    0000002c   15
    0000002b   15
    0000002a    0
    00000029    0
    00000009    0 <==
0000000e services.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001f    0
    00000014    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001e    0
    00000019    0
    00000018    0
    00000013    0
0000001c plugplay.exe
    00000022    0
    00000021    0
    0000001d    0
00000023 explorer.exe
    00000028    0
    00000027    0
    00000026    0
    00000025    0
    00000024    0
System information:
    Wine build: wine-2.0.4
    Platform: i386 (WOW64)
    Version: Windows 7
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.13.0-26-generic
```

The output in the terminal is this:

```
ironpig@ironpig-pc:~$ wine ~/Desktop/IronPig/Progs/Geometry\ Dash/GeometryDash.exe 
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33f434 (nil)): stub
fixme:xinput:XInputGetState (index 0, state 0x172658) Stub!
fixme:xinput:XInputGetStateEx (index 0, state 0x33fc88) Stub!
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x33f910 (nil)): stub
fixme:system:SetProcessDPIAware stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),0,0x33f88c,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW (L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1",0,0x33f544,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW (L"\\\\.\\DISPLAY1",1,0x33f544,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:win:EnumDisplayDevicesW ((null),1,0x33f88c,0x00000000), stub!
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 0x1004e 233 1 (nil)
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 0x1004e 4a 1 (nil)
fixme:msg:ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx 0x1004e 49 1 (nil)
fixme:ver:GetCurrentPackageId (0x1c4e9d8 (nil)): stub
wine: Unhandled page fault on read access to 0x0000000c at address 0xc1ec98 (thread 0009), starting debugger...
```

The worst thing is that this prevents me from creating a properly functioning desktop shortcut.

So, why is this happening and how can I create a working desktop shortcut?

I use:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- gnome-shell
- wine-2.0.4

Comment: We can't fix this; the problem is with a binary executable that we can not inspect.  I would have asked it here: https://forum.winehq.org/viewforum.php?f=2&sid=cf75badb77002ad62c049f2aadbbca28

Comment: In the `.desktop` file, include a `Path=/path/to/start/in` line.